# How can I make Ruby release unreferenced memory?

Tags: ruby, memory

Consider this snippet:

```
l = []

while 1
  l << 'a random 369-characterish string'
end
^C
# ran this for maybe 4 seconds, and it had 27 million entries in l. memory
# usage was 1.6 GB.

l = nil

# no change in memory usage

GC.start

# memory usage drops a relatively small amount, from 1.6 GB to 1.39 GB.
```

I am pushing millions of elements into/through Ruby's data structures, and having some serious memory issues. This example demonstrates that even in a case where there is no reference to an extant object, Ruby will not let [most of] it go, even after an explicit call to `GC.start`.

The objects I am using in real life push millions of elements into a hash in total, but the hash is used as a temporary lookup table and is zeroed out after some loop has completed. The memory from this lookup table, however, apparently never gets released, and this slows my application horrendously and progessively because the GC has millions of defunct objects to analyze on each cycle. I am working on a workaround with the `sparsehash` gem, but this doesn't seem like an intractable problem that the Ruby runtime should choke on like that. The references are clearly deleted, and the objects should clearly be collected and disposed. Can anyone help me figure out why this is not happening?

I have tried `l.delete_if { |x| true}` on the suggestion of a user in #ruby on freenode, but this was really slow and also never seemed to cause an appreciable release of memory.

Using `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]`.

EDIT:

For comparison, here is a run in `python3`:

```
l = []

while 1:
    l.append('a random 369-characterish string')
^C
# 31,216,082 elements; 246M memory usage.

l = []
# memory usage drops to 8K (0% of system total)
```

Test on python2 show near identical results.

I'm not sure if this is sufficient to consider this an implementation deficiency in MRI or if it just chalked up to different approaches to GC. Either way, it seems like Python is better suited to use cases that are going to push millions of elements in total through the data structures and periodically zero the structures out (like a one may do for a temporary look up table).

It really does seem like this should be a simple one. :\

Comment: I heard that ruby never releases memory to the system. It may clear and then reuse some of already allocated memory, but it doesn't release. The only option is to restart the process.

Comment: (It might be possible that a different Ruby implementation will serve better here: MRI, Rubinius, and JRuby are all likely to act differently due to using different GC implementations.)

Comment: @pst: Have tried JRuby for other pieces, but would like to avoid as it doesn't fully support all the modules I'm using and I don't want to split the script to have half run on JRuby and half run on MRI. Rubinius won't install for me and don't feel like fixing it unless we know it will really work well.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: It's not so much about the deallocation to the system as it's about MRI never really cleaning the objects out, so each successive GC pass gets slower and slower, eventually making the program crap out.

Though it does seem that MRI deallocates memory sometimes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: If you can find some evidence for that claim, it would certainly count as an answer.

Comment: It is not being garbage collected https://gist.github.com/3747823 I don't know why.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek because you always append the very same string object, which obviously can't be garbage collected as it is still referenced by your constant. However as you din't create many new strings, your example shouldn't take much memory at all.

Comment: @HolgerJust the array is not referenced by the constant, the string is. Why is the array not garbage collected?

Comment: i would try running this example with rubinius and compare the results. mri 1.9 has an improved garbage collector over 1.8, but it's still none-terministic. the garbage collector does not really "know" if an object can be released, so it's possible that some objects don't get released, eventhough they should.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Redis or Mongo...

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Because the Array `0` index is point to a constant and in Ruby Constant are never Garbage Collected.

Comment: @Viren Why does it matter what the array's 0 index points to? Nothing references the array, so it should be GC'd.

Comment: @phoet I just tried with `rubinius 3.48 (2.3.1 b39b6dda 2016-07-20 3.6.2) [x86_64-darwin15.5.0]`, Rubinius GC'd it, `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]` did not. Frankly, it seems like a bug in MRI.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek This is what I found in ruby-2.2.0. As you can see constant are never GC'd. `https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/41c55b81bb0038936786f47de8512a60`

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hacky, but you can try `fork`ing the operation off as a separate process. The process will run in shared memory space; when it terminates, the memory will be freed.

Ruby might not be releasing memory back to the Kernel as @Sergio Tulentsev pointed out in the comments.

This Ruby/Unix mailing list conversation describes this in detail: [Avoiding system calls](http://librelist.com/browser//usp.ruby/2011/9/14/system-calls-in-unix/#64f712adaf24057687b148d5e2de5bb7)

Also, this blog post describes forking as a solution for memory management in Rails: [Saving memory in Ruby on Rails with fork() and copy-on-write](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2007/04/05/saving-memory-in-ruby-on-rails/). Although, I don't think that Ruby will support copy-on-write until Ruby 2 comes out.